# Mule ESB, what version of XPath does it use

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, esb

I can not tell from the documentation, what version of XPath does Mule use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the 3.6.0 [release notes](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.6.0+Release+Notes), up until 3.5.2, Mule used Saxon 9.1.0.8 and this is being upgraded to 9.6.0.1-HE in Mule 3.6.0. According to the [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE) documentation page, the more recent version ensure full XPath 2.0 and and 3.0.

HTH

Comment: In 3.6.0 the new <code>xpath3</code> function was added to support xpath 3. For better understanding which version is available at each Mule version I recommend you to see this blog post: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3 HTH, Marcos